# How to search by an array in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a string which can contain any number of words separated by a space. I am sending this string as a parameter from vb to sql via sqlCommand. How can i split this into an array in sql or send it as array from vb altogether to search the table.

The sql search must return all those rows in which each row contains all the words from the string that i have passed.

Comment: How are the words stored in the table? Are the words sorted?

Comment: no, the words aren't sorted

Comment: Try a table valued parameter if you're using SQL server 2008 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim command As New SqlCommand("sp_GetCustomerByIDS", connection)
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
    'Here is how you pass in YourString seperated with comma's
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerIDS", YourString.Replace(" ", ","))
    ...
End Using
```

The comma separated string of values is passed into the Stored Procedure (tip: please change the *ntext* as SQL2005/SQL2008+ have **varchar(MAX)** ):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetCustomerByIDS]
@CustomerIDS ntext
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @err int
declare @TempTbl as TABLE(mystrings nvarchar(32), i1 int, i2 int, i3 int)
INSERT @TempTbl exec @err = sp_SplitTextList @CustomerIDS, ','

SELECT *
FROM   dbo.Customers
WHERE 
dbo.Customers.ID in (select mystrings from @TempTbl)

END
```

I use this SplitTextList stored procedure to process the comma separated values, again you might want to change @list_text from text to varchar(MAX), you can see from the history its quite old:

```
/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
-- uspSplitTextList
--
-- Description:
--      splits a separated list of text items and returns the text items
--
-- Arguments:
--      @list_text              - list of text items
--      @Delimiter              - delimiter
--
-- Notes:
-- 02/22/2006 - WSR : use DATALENGTH instead of LEN throughout because LEN doesn't count trailing blanks
--
-- History:
-- 02/22/2006 - WSR : revised algorithm to account for items crossing 8000 character boundary
--
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SplitTextList]
    @list_text              text,
   @Delimiter               varchar(3)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @InputLen           integer         -- input text length
DECLARE @TextPos            integer         -- current position within input text
DECLARE @Chunk              varchar(8000)   -- chunk within input text
DECLARE @ChunkPos           integer         -- current position within chunk
DECLARE @DelimPos           integer         -- position of delimiter
DECLARE @ChunkLen           integer         -- chunk length
DECLARE @DelimLen           integer         -- delimiter length
DECLARE @ItemBegPos     integer         -- item starting position in text
DECLARE @ItemOrder      integer         -- item order in list
DECLARE @DelimChar      varchar(1)      -- first character of delimiter (simple delimiter)

-- create table to hold list items
-- actually their positions because we may want to scrub this list eliminating bad entries before substring is applied
CREATE TABLE #list_items ( item_order integer, item_begpos integer, item_endpos integer )

-- process list
IF @list_text IS NOT NULL
   BEGIN
    -- initialize
   SET @InputLen = DATALENGTH(@list_text)
   SET @TextPos = 1
   SET @DelimChar = SUBSTRING(@Delimiter, 1, 1)
   SET @DelimLen = DATALENGTH(@Delimiter)
   SET @ItemBegPos = 1
   SET @ItemOrder = 1
   SET @ChunkLen = 1

   -- cycle through input processing chunks
   WHILE @TextPos <= @InputLen AND @ChunkLen <> 0
      BEGIN
      -- get current chunk
      SET @Chunk = SUBSTRING(@list_text, @TextPos, 8000)

      -- setup initial variable values
      SET @ChunkPos = 1
      SET @ChunkLen = DATALENGTH(@Chunk)
      SET @DelimPos = CHARINDEX(@DelimChar, @Chunk, @ChunkPos)

      -- loop over the chunk, until the last delimiter
      WHILE @ChunkPos <= @ChunkLen AND @DelimPos <> 0
         BEGIN

    -- see if this is a full delimiter
         IF SUBSTRING(@list_text, (@TextPos + @DelimPos - 1), @DelimLen) = @Delimiter
            BEGIN

        -- insert position
             INSERT INTO #list_items (item_order, item_begpos, item_endpos)
             VALUES (@ItemOrder, @ItemBegPos, (@TextPos + @DelimPos - 1) - 1)

             -- adjust positions
             SET @ItemOrder = @ItemOrder + 1
             SET @ItemBegPos = (@TextPos + @DelimPos - 1) + @DelimLen
             SET @ChunkPos = @DelimPos + @DelimLen
        END
         ELSE
            BEGIN

            -- adjust positions
            SET @ChunkPos = @DelimPos + 1
            END

         -- find next delimiter      
         SET @DelimPos = CHARINDEX(@DelimChar, @Chunk, @ChunkPos)
         END

      -- adjust positions
      SET @TextPos = @TextPos + @ChunkLen
      END

    -- handle last item
   IF @ItemBegPos <= @InputLen
      BEGIN

      -- insert position
      INSERT INTO #list_items (item_order, item_begpos, item_endpos)
      VALUES (@ItemOrder, @ItemBegPos, @InputLen)

      END

    -- delete the bad items
   DELETE FROM #list_items
   WHERE item_endpos < item_begpos

   -- return list items
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@list_text, item_begpos, (item_endpos - item_begpos + 1)) AS item_text, item_order, item_begpos, item_endpos
   FROM #list_items
   ORDER BY item_order
   END
DROP TABLE #list_items
RETURN
```

Comment: Am I missing something? Where did you get the schema for the table? "The sql search must return all those rows in which each row contains all the words from the string that i have passed". The IN statement will not satisfy the requirement OP put forth. According to OP table has a string column with words separated by space. That column should have all words passed by parameter.

Comment: @AlexS I dont feel good about this answer, its from code I wrote 9 years ago. When I get time I'll work out and add the table variable approach. Hopefully Evan M will add it in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using table parameters, you can parse the string into a table variable.  This is what the pseudocode would be like:

```
Declare a table variable with one VARCHAR column
While the string is not empty
    Grab everything up to the first space and insert it into the table variable
    Remove the first word from the string
```

Once you have the temporary table, you can join it using LIKE with your source table.  For each row in your source table, the join creates a row for every word that matched in the array.  You can then use GROUP/HAVING to limit that down to only the results that returned a row for each entry in your table variable (meaning those that match every string in the table variable).

For example:

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (Word VARCHAR(100))

...
-- Put logic from the pseudocode above to populate @TempTable from your string
...

SELECT Y.PrimaryKey, MAX(Y.MaybeYouNeedThisColumnToo) from YourTable Y
INNER JOIN @TempTable temp
ON Y.ColumnToMatch LIKE '%' + temp.Word + '%'
GROUP BY Y.PrimaryKey
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TempTable)
```

Comment: can you explain with an example?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show this with a copy-paste example without the pseudo code.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]  
(  
    @String NVARCHAR(MAX)  
)  
RETURNS @OutputTable TABLE  
(  
    [Value] NVARCHAR(MAX)  
)  
AS  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @Value NVARCHAR(MAX)  
    DECLARE @Pos INT  
    DECLARE @Piece NVARCHAR(MAX)  

    SET @String = LTRIM(RTRIM(@String)) + ' '  
    SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(' ', @String, 1)  

    WHILE @Pos > 0  
    BEGIN  
        SET @Piece = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@String, @Pos - 1)))  
        IF @Piece <> ''  
        BEGIN  
            INSERT INTO @OutputTable ([Value])  
            VALUES (@Piece)  
        END  
        SET @String = RIGHT(@String, LEN(@String) - @Pos)  
        SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(' ', @String, 1)  
    END  

    RETURN  
END
```

To split a string into an array in SQL, you can create a user-defined function like the one above. This function takes a string as input and returns a table with each word as a separate row.

1. The function `SplitString` takes a string `@String` as input.
2. It initializes variables for processing the string.
3. It trims the input string and appends a space for consistent processing.
4. It iterates over the string, finding each word separated by spaces.
5. Each word is inserted into the @OutputTable if it is not empty.
6. The function returns the table with individual words.

To use this function in your SQL query for searching rows containing all words from the input string, you can pass the string from VB.NET to SQL and utilize the split function to search efficiently based on each word.